# how to change the font size of all text box within a grid, windows app uwp

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp, uwp-xaml

I know how to develop webpages with HTML and CSS, but I am new to the windows app development and I am trying to develop an universal windows platform (UWP) application.

Lets say I have grid,

```
 <Grid Name="Grid1">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers> 
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="text1.FontSize" Value="12" />
                    <Setter Target="text2.FontSize" Value="12" />
                    <Setter Target="text3.FontSize" Value="10" />                        
                </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Name="text1" FontSize="22" Text="hello text">    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Name="text2" FontSize="22" Text="hello text1">    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Name="text3" FontSize="22" Text="hello text2">    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Is it is possible to change the font size of all text box with single VisualState.Setters like how we do in with CSS class in HTML ?, because I have to change many text box font size based on window width.

Sorry if if the question is too silly and absurd. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use styles to apply same values for all controls. Consider next example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="hello text" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="hello text1" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="hello text2" />
</Grid>
```

**Edited**

You can set a named style in a Setter of VisualState:

```
<Grid Name="Grid1">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                ...
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="text1.Style" Value="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" />
                    ...
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    ...
</Grid>
```

Comment: but i want to achieve that in VisualStateManager, so that I can have responsive UI. This didnt work within VisualStateManager.

Comment: You can place all your controls in some panel and change a property (maybe attached property) of this panel in a "Setter". All child controls will inherit this value if they don't have any. In your example you can use TextElement.FontSize: <Setter Target="panel1.(TextElement.FontSize)" Value="20"/>